# Is overriding Equals to exclude some fields in the comparison going to cause a problem with Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have some model and view model classes with "last updated date/time" and "last updated by user" fields.  I'm overriding the `Equals` method so that it doesn't compare those two fields, like this:

I noticed when I use Automapper to map from a view model to a model, it's calling `Equals` during that mapping.  **Is the fact that I'm not comparing those two fields within `Equals` going to cause any problems with Automapper?**  Everything appears to be working, but I want to make sure nothing is going to go wrong in certain situations later.

The fact that `Equals` is getting called seems to be related to using Entity Framework and calling `UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel`.  If I remove the call to `UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel`, then `Equals` does not get called.

```
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.EquivalencyExpression;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class MyModel : IEquatable<MyModel>
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime DttmLastUpdated { get; set; }

    // Do not compare by LastUpdatedBy or DttmLastUpdated
    public bool Equals(MyModel obj)
    {
        return this.Field1.Equals(obj.Field1) && this.Field2.Equals(obj.Field2);
    }
}

public class MyViewModel : IEquatable<MyViewModel>
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime DttmLastUpdated { get; set; }

    // Do not compare by LastUpdatedBy or DttmLastUpdated
    public bool Equals(MyViewModel obj)
    {
        return this.Field1.Equals(obj.Field1) && this.Field2.Equals(obj.Field2);
    }
}

public class MyParentModel
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public virtual List<MyModel> Children { get; set; }
}

public class MyParentViewModel
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public List<MyViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}

// Entity Framework mapping
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = "(local)\\sqlexpress",
            InitialCatalog = "LocalTest",
            IntegratedSecurity = true
        };

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(builder.ToString());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>(eb =>
        {
            eb.HasKey(k => new { k.Field1, k.Field2 });
            eb.ToTable("Child");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyParentModel>(eb =>
        {
            eb.HasKey(k => new { k.Field1 });
            eb.ToTable("Parent");
        });
    }
}

// ...

public void DoTheThing()
{
   var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
   {
      cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
      cfg.UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel<MyContext>();
      cfg.CreateMap<MyParentViewModel, MyParentModel>();
      cfg.CreateMap<MyViewModel, MyModel>();
   });

   var parentModel = new MyParentModel
   {
       Children = new List<MyModel>
       {
          new MyModel { Field1 = "AAA", Field2 = "BBB" }
       }
   };

   var parentViewModel = new MyParentViewModel
   {
       Children = new List<MyViewModel>
       {
          new MyViewModel { Field1 = "111", Field2 = "222" }
       }
   };

   var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

   // Calling Map causes MyModel.Equals to be called
   mapper.Map(parentViewModel, parentModel, parentViewModel.GetType(), parentModel.GetType());  
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve]. Maybe it's an error that it is calling `Equals()` at all. Why should it call `Equals()`?

Comment: Adding an `Equals` method is not the same as overriding equals. Try adding `public override bool Equals(object obj)` (and override `GetHashcode` also) if it's not working as you expect.

Comment: @Progman I updated my example with reproducible code, although it'll also need the data specified in my EF mapping to be created locally in order to be executable.

Comment: @RufusL After some testing, it appears that the fact that `Equals` is getting called is related to using Entity Framework with `UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel`

Comment: @BenRubin, I am facing the same sort of issue. Is there any config to avoid calling the override `Equals ` method or any workaround?